# Mootools get second class name

Tags: mootools

I see the method of getting second class name with jquery but how do I do it in mootools , my element is `<li class="parent active">`

I need to match full class name like li.parent.active and adjust height if that class is present I tried
 `$$('li').hasClass('parent active')`  or getProperty  but all of them return true even if active is not present, if  I add  **.parent.active** I get

*The expression is not a legal expression*.  now I **must** support mootols 1.1 ,1.2 ,1.3 working on CMS here so I started with the ugly one 1.1 version

this is how is actually needed

```
var holderdiv =$('mymenu');
if($$('li.parent.active')){holderdiv.setStyle({'height':'50px'});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if($$('li.parent.active') == true)` returns true as in, it's truthy (defined, not null).

if you mean to say: is there at least one child element that has .parent and .active, you can do:

```
if (holderdiv.getElement("li.parent.active")) // at least one.
    holderDiv.setStyle("height", 50); // setStyle uses a value pair, not an object.
```

if they are not children of holderdiv just do `document.getElement` or `whateverElObj.getElement` instead.

**this will likely break in 1.11 due to old xpath stuff.**

one way to do it so it works in all versions would be this (though you should only do this if MooTools.version is wrong due to performance cost of double loops):

```
var holderdiv = $("holderdiv");

if (holderdiv.getElements("li.parent").some(function(el){ return el.hasClass("active"); })) {
    // at least one.
    holderdiv.setStyle("height", 50);
}
```

the `.some` will run through all `li.parent` until it finds one that matches the condition (`hasClass("active")`) and then return boolean true else, false.

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/BqwAk/

if you need to keep a reference of the lis into a collection, use `.filter` instead:

```
var lis = holderdiv.getElements("li.parent").filter(function(el){ 
    return el.hasClass("active"); 
});
```

if all have .parent and only one can be active, you don't really care so you can just do

```
if (holderdiv.getElement("li.active"))
```

or

```
if (holderdiv.getElement("li.active").hasClass("parent"))
```

... to double check if they don't all have .parent.

Comment: should hire you for some JS magic. not joking here. awesome instruction

Answer (score 0):

You could simply match all elements with both classes `parent` and `active` and set their style, MooTools makes that easy:

```
$$('li.parent.active').setStyle({'height':'50px'});
```

Comment: tried that , like advised moo 1.1  wont do it ,  I think  from 1.2  you gcan get full name

Comment: this is how is need   if($$('li.parent.active') == true){holderdiv.setStyle({'height':'50px'});

Comment: yes , just tested ,   full class name works from 1.2  and up  but 1.1  no go

Comment: @Benn: That doesn't make any sense. What is `$$(…) == true` supposed to do? `$$` returns a list of Elements on which you then can perform certain operations. Are your `<li>` elements supposed to be child elements of your `holderdiv`? (i.e. `$$('#mymenu li.parent.active')`). Try including the CSS extensions from MooTools. Better yet: upgrade to a more recent version (1.4 is current)!

Comment: please read my question I advised that I MUST support all versions starting from 1.1